# Is there a way in which when I upload a image it'll redirect to another tab and my page redirects there on uploading image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically what I'm trying to do is that I'm making a component like WordPress uploading images. When I upload an image my tab section automatically changes to the second tab on uploading and it'll stack there in my images gallery 'div'.I have uploaded the image to another tab section but redirecting isn't performed I have to click other tab to see the uploaded image and the rest of the images aren't showing the style I added on the active image is also not getting.

HTML Reference

```
<div class="custom-row web-align-center web-gap-10 img-container">
   <div class="item-img pos-relative">
       <img src="{{ asset('imgs/admin/home-decor-2.webp') }}" alt="">
         <div class="tick">
           <img src=" {{ asset('imgs/admin/icons/select.svg') }} " alt="">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-img pos-relative">
       <img src="{{ asset('imgs/admin/home-decor-2.webp') }}" alt="">
        <div class="tick">
          <img src=" {{ asset('imgs/admin/icons/select.svg') }} " alt="">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-img pos-relative">
      <img src="{{ asset('imgs/admin/home-decor-2.webp') }}" alt="">
        <div class="tick">
           <img src=" {{ asset('imgs/admin/icons/select.svg') }} " alt="">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-img pos-relative">
    <img src="{{ asset('imgs/admin/home-decor-2.webp') }}" alt="">
      <div class="tick">
          <img src=" {{ asset('imgs/admin/icons/select.svg') }} " alt="">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-img pos-relative">
    <img src="{{ asset('imgs/admin/home-decor-2.webp') }}" alt="" >
       <div class="tick">
          <img src=" {{ asset('imgs/admin/icons/select.svg') }} " alt="">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS for Reference

```
// gallery start
let files = [], // will be store images
form = document.querySelector(".browse-area"),
container = document.querySelector(".img-container"),
text = document.querySelector(".inner"),
browse = document.querySelector(".select"),
input = document.querySelector(".browse-area input");

browse.addEventListener("click", () => input.click());

 // input change event
input.addEventListener("change", () => {
let file = input.files;

for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    if (files.every((e) => e.name !== file[i].name)) files.push(file[i]);
}

// form.reset();
showImages();
});

 const showImages = () => {
 let images = "";
 files.forEach((e, i) => {
    images += `<div class="item-img pos-relative">
            <img src="${URL.createObjectURL(e)}" alt="image">
            <div class="tick">
                <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/imgs/admin/icons/select.svg" alt="" 
  onclick="delImage(${i})">
            </div>
        </div>`;
 });

 container.innerHTML = images;
 };

 const delImage = (index) => {
 files.splice(index, 1);
 showImages();
  };

 // drag and drop
 form.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();

 form.classList.add("dragover");
 text.innerHTML = "Drop images here";
 });

 form.addEventListener("dragleave", (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();

 form.classList.remove("dragover");
 text.innerHTML =
    'Drag & drop image here or <span class="select">Browse</span>';
  });

  form.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  form.classList.remove("dragover");
  text.innerHTML =
    'Drag & drop image here or <span class="select">Browse</span>';

  let file = e.dataTransfer.files;
  for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    if (files.every((e) => e.name !== file[i].name)) files.push(file[i]);
   }

  showImages();
  });
  // gallery end
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezyvy.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j2sC.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyJFe.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.